# How to prove that this morphism is an homotopy equivalence but not an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

The following question was asked in my assignment of Algebraic Topology but I am not able to make any significant progress on this question. I am adding it's image here not mathjax because it uses very hard mathjax formulae. I have been studying from my class notes so far but Instructor has given Hatcher's book as a reference.

Question: [image]

A morphism of complexes $f : C \to D$ is the data of a family of R-linear
morphisms $f_i : C_i \to D_i$, $i \in  \mathbb{Z}$ which preserves the differentials:
$d \circ f_i = f_{i−1} \circ d$ for all i.

$f : C\to D$ is a homotopy equivalence if there exists $g:D\to C$ such that $f\circ g \simeq Id_D$ and $g\circ f \simeq Id_C$ , here g is called a homotopy inverse of f. We say that C and D are homotopy equivalent complexes if there exists a homotopy equivalence $f:C \to D$.

I don't have much to show as what I did in the problem . I will not be able to do it myself.

Any hints please?

Comment: It's obviously not an isomorphism. It's not injective! So the question is really about showing that it is a homotopy equivalence (of complexes). Hatcher doesn't do a good job on this, so maybe you want to look somewhere else for this e.g. Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch:** Find $g$ such that $f \circ g = \mathrm{Id}_D$. Now look at $k = g \circ f - \mathrm{Id}_c$. For an appropriate choice of $g$ and $dx = 0$ (with $x \in C$) you should get that $kx$ is in the image of $d_C$. Now use this to determine the homotopy $k \simeq 0$ (which consists of a single non-zero map $C_0 \to C_1$).